# Firebase authentication with role checking

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

so i am very new to firebase and whole noSql database area. And i am now working at some flutter based project that use firebase as the backend and database.

so i am building something like uber but for sending things and i am creating 4 different user role there is

1. Buyer
2. Seller
3. Driver
4. Receiver (buyer also can act as receiver but, i for user with role receiver than they only can receive things not ordering)

And in my app when user gonna login or register they gonna choose first they will login or register as what role. Now in laravel or php in general i can easily built a checker or some field on the database that indicate the user role and whenever user login or register it will not only check for email for unique field but also with the role.

so i can have MyAwesomeEmail@email.com in role Seller and Buyer each. But in firebase when i first register as MyAwesomeEmail@email.com then the next time i register again it will say this email is already been use which is true because i got no way to add some fields to indicate this email is already taken for seller role, but not been used yet for buyer role.

So how to fix it? am i doing it wrong with firebase? or firebase because of its simplicity that it don't offer flexibility like building our own backend?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication deal with the **authentication** of users only. When using email+password authentication that means that the user types the correct combination of email and password.

If your application assigns a role to each user, it should do so in a way that doesn't require different credentials. If the same user can perform multiple roles, you should build your UI that allows them to enter their credentials separately from the role selection.

A typical flow may be:

```
Select role -> Enter email -+-> Enter password
                            |
                            +-> Enter registration details
```

So after entering their email address, you check if the email address is already registered in that role. If so, ask for their password. If not, you ask them to enter registration details for the role.